# How do I authenticate when testing a GET to Webhooks

Tags: webhooks, zapier

I am using Zapier Webhooks with Airtable with the intention that when there is a new record in my Airtable, I can take action with the webhook!

However, I am having trouble setting up the API on Zapier.

[image: Here are the steps I have taken]

**Here is where I am getting the error:** And I think it's because I am not authorizing properly, because afterwards it says:

[image]

I know my values are correct because when I make a CURL request, I use the following:

```
curl "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appyRAw7MAgenvkqu/RTS" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer MY_KEY_HERE | json_pp
```

And I am returned with proper JSON... but through Zapier, I cannot get past this step.

Answer (score 2):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I did a little digging here and it turns out there's a bug on Airtable's end  (which has now been reported) where the `User-Agent: Zapier` header (which we send by default) causes API calls to 404. There are two solutions:

1. Overwrite the `User-Agent` header with anything else
2. Use the table id instead of the table name in the url

I've tested each and found that it works as expected. Here's a picture of my successful setup:

[image]

Sorry about that confusion. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I decided to use `New Record in View` and use `Zapier Webhook` to send a a POST request to my server. I skipped authenticity for that API call, thus making it a whole lot easier.